# How to print out memory address of UNIX application's memory using C?

Tags: c, unix, memory, memory-management, memory-address

Does anyone know how to print out memory addresses of UNIX application's memory using C?

I need to print out those information of addresses when I run my code, for instance 'the number of pages of physical memory'

The output i'm looking for this example is something like...

```
Number of pages:
          384285
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to print out a memory *address*, or an *amount* of memory consumed by or allocated to something, or something else?

Comment: Even deciding what physical memory "belongs to" the process is nontrivial; there's no clear-cut definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char buf[40];
sprintf(buf, "exec cat /proc/%d/status", getpid());
system(buf);
```

Comment: First, why not use `/proc/self/status`? Second, this gives a lot of information the OP's not asking for.

Comment: Because /proc/self/status would give the data for the cat process.

Comment: Ah, right. Oops. Well, he could still open `/proc/self/status` and pump the data within the process - but that leaves the problem of figuring out what the heck the OP wants exactly

Comment: @Joshua: Depends on whether you used `cat /proc/self/status` or `cat` by itself after opening `/proc/self/status` as stdin.. :-)